# add UIPageControl to titleView swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to add a UIPageControl to my navigationBar through the titleView, but nothing is shown in the navigationBar. I've tried adding the pageControl to a UIView and then add the UIView to the titleView, but as i said no response. How can i achieve this?

```
var pageControl: UIPageControl?
var pageView: UIView?


    pageView?.frame = CGRectZero
    pageView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    pageControl?.frame = CGRectZero
    pageControl?.currentPage = 0
    pageControl?.numberOfPages = 3
    pageControl?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pageView?.addSubview(pageControl!)
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView = pageView?
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with the pageView.  But you need to create an instance of the pageControl, and add it to navigationItem of the current viewController, not the navigationController's navigationItem.

```
var pageControl: UIPageControl?
pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl?.frame = CGRectZero
pageControl?.currentPage = 0
pageControl?.numberOfPages = 3
pageControl?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationItem.titleView = pageControl?
```

Comment: Okay this creates an issue since i only have 1 leftBarButton in the navigationBar the pageControl will not be centered? how can i center it

Comment: Have you tried putting in a hidden right bar button item?